# Cloudflare SSL certificate doesnt work on Nginx and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, cloudflare

I have the cert.pem and the key.pem of Cloudflare on my ubuntu server of AWS. I've configured nginx and when I try to enter to my website I get this error. "SSL Certificate no valid". I dont know what I am doing wrong.
NGINX CONFIGURATION
[This is the nginx configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2MXu.png)

ERROR
[This is the error (I should only get an 200 status)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB1tu.png)

Please I need help to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

What is the configuration on the SSL/TLS section in Cloudflare? It will probably work in "Full", not in "Full (Strict)". Also, if end to end encryption is not a hard requirement, you can listen on port 80 and set SSL/TLS in Cloudflare in "Flexible" mode in which the connection is encrypted between the client and the Cloudflare proxy and from the proxy to your server it is going to be unencrypted.

Comment: Thanks for aswering. It is "Full", and I has to be end to end encrypted.